# What is this small white flower, sprouting out of a single large leaf?

Tags: identification, flowers, wildflowers

I recently found this flower on a north facing, shady bank in woodland (UK) with sandy soil. I've never seen anything like it before, a small, white flower sprouting out of a single, large leaf. What is it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is [*Claytonia perfoliata*,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claytonia_perfoliata) known as Miner's Lettuce in the US.  It's often used as a salad green in winter lettuce mixes.  It's extraordinarily cold hardy.  Not much flavor though (at least in my opinion).

Comment: +1 Miner's lettuce. Graze on it as you weed, it is a good source of water at least.